# Strike-through overflows on side-by-side markdown

Tags: bug, revisions-list

[image]

The revision in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18243648/revisions).

There's also another overflow-type, but for side-by-side instead:

[image]

The revision for that question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18681544/revisions).

I am running `Windows 7 x64` on `Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m`.

Comment: I have no such thing in Firefox 23 on Windows 8.1. What browser do you use?

Comment: Have you linked the wrong question's revision?

Comment: No repro here. Chrome Mobile 28.0.1500.16 with WebKit 536.26 (iOS 6.1.3)

Comment: @hims056 no. That's correct. Look at the image's text.

Comment: Yes repro in Chrome: 28.0.1500.95 m Windows XP.

Comment: Must be something with Blink then

Comment: I repro with the exact same system configuration. Which adds nothing to the discussion, other than "hey, he's not lying!"

Comment: Repro in Safari 6.0.5 on a Mac. Better now, @CodyGray?

Comment: Yes repro on Linux using Chrome 28.0.1500.52.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 23.0.1 on Windows 7 x64. No repro first; yes repro second.